# Verificação e confirmação de dias

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

convidados_df = pd.read_excel('Cadastro.xlsx')

rg_input = int(input('Digite o RG: '))

convidados_df.loc[convidados_df['RG'] == rg_input, 'PrimeiroDia'] = 'Confirmado'
convidados_df.loc[convidados_df['RG'] == rg_input, 'SegundoDia'] = 'Confirmado'
convidados_df.loc[convidados_df['RG'] == rg_input, 'TerceiroDia'] = 'Confirmado'

convidados_df

# convidados_df.to_excel('Cadastro.xlsx')
```

Preciso criar uma logica onde eu consiga confirmar cada convidado separadamente, dessa forma que eu fiz ele esta sendo confirmado os dia todos ao mesmo tempo, no primeiro input, porem eu quero confirmar cada um separadamente, se eu colocar a informação do RG dele confirma um dia, se eu adicionar de novo ele verifica se no primeiro dia esta confirmado e se estiver confirma no segundo e assim sucessivamente, porem estou com bastante dificuldade de construir essa logica.

Comment: Faz um favor, leia como criar um [mcve] e adicione uma amostra em texto da planilha(para testes) e nos contextualize melhor sobre o problema pois *"...Preciso criar uma logica onde eu consiga confirmar cada convidado separadamente..."* para quem não está envolvido no seu projeto essa frase não possui muito significado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer seria usando boleano (pode ser com 1 e 0 se preferir):

### Criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd

convidados_df = pd.DataFrame({'RG': ['111', '222', '333', '444'], 'PrimeiroDia': [False, False, False, False], 'SegundoDia': [False, False, False, False], 'TerceiroDia': [False, False, False, False],})
```

### Lógica

```
colunas = ['PrimeiroDia', 'SegundoDia', 'TerceiroDia']

rg_input = input('Digite o RG: ')

soma = convidados_df.loc[convidados_df['RG'] == rg_input, colunas].sum(axis=1).values

if len(soma) > 0:
    idx = soma[0]
    if idx >= len(colunas):
        print("Convidado confirmado para todos os dias")
    else:
        convidados_df.loc[convidados_df['RG'] == rg_input, colunas[idx]] = True
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor informar o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta

Comment: Cara, nao sei quem foi, a resposta pra min foi boa, nao funcional para o que eu precisava no momento, mais vai servir para futuros projetos.

quando eu utilizo a sua resposta, ele ta fazendo a tabela toda confirmar, como se todas as pessoas estivesse ido no evento na mesma hora.